# SQL : map column several times to item

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am new to SQL and is trying to retrieve all names from mapped id | name table.

Structure looks like this:

[image]

[image]

My goal is to return a complete item with all columns, but the id columns are replaced with a real value.

I can use this code to retrieve 1 tag (only problem with tags since that's the only column that is not 1:1 mapped):

```
select Posts.Title as Title, Tags.Name as Tag1
from Posts 
inner join Tags on Posts.Tag1ID = Tags.TagID
```

[image]

But I can't figure out how to get all values from Tag1ID, Tag2ID, Tag3ID and Tag4ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poor data model, but you can use `join` . . . and `join` again and again:

```
select p.Title as Title, t1.Name as Tag1, t2.Name as Tag2,
       . . .
from Posts p left join
     tags t1
     on p.Tag1ID = t1.TagID left join
     Posts p left join
     tags t2
     on p.Tag1ID = t2.TagID left join
     . . .
```

You need to repeat this for every tag column.

If you can, you should fix the data model!  A better data model would have a `PostTags` table with one row per post and per tag.

Comment: Yeah fixing the structure a bit sounds good